# Выровнять колонки по высоте по меньшему блоку

Tags: вёрстка

Как выровнять рядом стоящие блоки по высоте, чтобы все стали высотой как самый меньший, и обрезались через свойство overflow: hidden; 
Не задавая фиксированной высоты

Answer (score 0):

Может так попробовать.

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
  font-size:0;
  background-color: #76a6f7;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  
}

.col-left {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.col-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam facilisis lobortis est. Phasellus sagittis, ex ut varius convallis, nisi sem facilisis metus, quis pretium est elit at massa.
    </div>
    <div class="col col-right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam facilisis lobortis est. Phasellus sagittis, ex ut varius convallis, nisi sem facilisis metus, quis pretium est elit at massa.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam facilisis lobortis est. Phasellus sagittis, ex ut varius convallis, nisi sem facilisis metus, quis pretium est elit at massa.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня два блока с картинками, в первом блоке короткая по вертикали , а во втором длинная. Плюс задача была настроить адаптивность (а следовательно высота не может быть фиксированной, так как картинка сожмётся/размажется. Абсолютное позиционирование конечно в планы не входило, но если это единственный способ, то использую ваш метод. Спасибо большое.